# Display RecyclerView after ToListAsync()

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview, sqlite-net

Hy, I want to display the resuilt of SQLite.net query with my RecyclerView in my Xamarin.Android app. When excecuting the query synchronous everythin works fine. but when I excecute it async, the Recyclerview won't show up. I checked the result of the query and it contains all the expected entries.
This works:

```
songsEntryArray = MusicShareDatabase.Instance.Database.Table<SongsEntry>().ToArray();

mRecyclerView = rootView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.allsongs_recyclerview);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(songsEntryArray);
mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this doesn't work:

```
var query = MusicShareDatabase.Instance.DatabaseAsync.Table<SongsEntry>();

query.ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
   mRecyclerView = rootView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.allsongs_recyclerview);
   mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
   mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   mAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(t.Result.ToArray());
   mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
   mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
   mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `ContinueWith(Action action)` is running on the background thread.

You need to run this code on the `UIThread` with method `Activity.RunOnUiThread(Action action);`.

**Code**

```
query.ToListAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
   Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
       mRecyclerView = rootView.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.allsongs_recyclerview);
       mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity);
       mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       mAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(t.Result.ToArray());
       mAdapter.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
       mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
       mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    });
});
```